# Как в lubuntu 16.04 определить микроконтролер STM32 и как его прошить?

Tags: stm32, hex, прошивка, connection

Имеется STM32L053 Nucleo-64 проверял через винду светодиод постоянно горел красный. Теперь подключил к lubuntu мерцает красный на stlink и МК, в течение 3 секунд после чего перестает мигать. Для прошивки установил STLINK
Этапы работы:
1 Доп пакеты:

> apt-get install gcc build-essential cmake libusb-1.0 libusb-1.0-0-dev libgtk-3-dev pandoc

> arm-none-eabi-gcc arm-none-eabi-gdb //получил hex файл

Сама установка:

> 1. Change into the project source directory: `cd stlink`
> 2. Run `make clean` -- required by some linux variants.
> 3. Run `make release` to create the *Release* target
> 4. Run `make install` to full install the package with complete system integration
> 5. Run `make debug` to create the *Debug* target (*optional*)
>        The debug target is only necessary in order to modify the sources and
>    to run under a debugger.
> 6. Run `make package`to build a Debian Package. The generated packages can be found in the subdirectory `./build/dist`.

Программа установилась и появилась в операционной системе. Но светодиоды так же себя ведут, мерцают 3 секунды оба на stlink и МК.
Вот что пишет прога stlink:

> st-util
> st-util 1.7.0-88-g9605d21
> /etc/stlink/chips: No such file or directory // нет такой директории, может что-то до установить надо
> 2021-08-01T19:35:09 WARN usb.c: Couldn't find any ST-Link devices

Если успеть в эти три секунды мерцания, ответ будет дольше на эти 3 секунды) и результат тот же.

Есть предположения, что нет драйверов каких-нибудь.

Подскажите какие есть идеи как подружить МК с компом и hex закинуть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причиной ошибки был не исправный кабель.